# How to replace strings from two different multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I try to replace strings from two different multidimensional arrays, using `str_replace` and categorized arrays.

I tried to use `array_walk_recursive` twice: one outside, and one inside, as you can see below

```
$array1 = [
    'key1' => [
        'first string'
    ],
    'key2' => [
        'second array'
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    'key1' => [
        'new string from second array'
    ],
    'key2' => [
        'second key in this other multidimensional array'
    ]
];

$outer_string = "Hello, this is my first string\nAnd here you can see another string from my second array";

echo array_walk_recursive($array1, function(&$e1, $i1) {
    return array_walk_recursive($array2, function(&$e2, $i2) {
        return str_replace($e1, $e2, $outer_string);
    });
});
```

I expect it to iterate over each key from the first array, and replace it with the values of the same key inside the second array. the string should be `"Hello, this is my new string from second array\nAnd here you can see another string from my second key in this other multidimensional array"`

Comment: replace the value or the key?

Comment: @JonathanK where the part of the string is equal to `"Hello, this is my $array1['key1][0]"` replace it with `$array2['key2'][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly simple solution to this problem is to iterate through the two arrays, building an array of replacement pairs (based on matching keys between the two arrays), and then passing this array to [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$replacements = array();
foreach ($array1 as $k => $v) {
    $replacements[$v[0]] = $array2[$k][0];
}
echo strtr($outer_string, $replacements);
```

Output:

```
Hello, this is my new string from second array
And here you can see another string from my second key in this other multidimensional array
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FETqi)

Comment: i'm looking for a solution without `foreach` because string might be long (like an HTML page) and arrays might be bigger

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `array_walk` internally does a foreach.